# Curl call stopped working after version update, TLS, SSL?

Tags: ssl, curl, tls1.2

I'm trying to make a very simple curl call, that works on one version of curl, but does not work on newer version, not sure why.

```
ᐅ docker run php:7.1.17 curl --version                   
curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2l zlib/1.2.8 libidn2/0.16 libpsl/0.17.0 (+libidn2/0.16) libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.18.1 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL                                                                                                     

ᐅ docker run php:7.1.16 curl --version                   
curl 7.38.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.38.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1t zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.29 libssh2/1.4.3 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

The version of `openssl` is same: `OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020` so I think it's not related to the issue.

Now, when I try to make a CURL call with the old version of curl, it works fine, the response is 200:

```
ᐅ docker run php:7.1.16 curl -v -s 'https://android.clients.google.com/auth' \ 
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \                    
--data-urlencode 'Email=myemail@gmail.com' \
--data-urlencode 'EncryptedPasswd=LongEncryptedPassword'     
...
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
...
> POST /auth HTTP/1.1
...
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
SID=BAD_COOKIE
LSID=BAD_COOKIE
services=mail,hist,multilogin,android%
```

but trying to make identical call for newer version of curl:

```
ᐅ docker run php:7.1.17 curl -v -s 'https://android.clients.google.com/auth' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'Email=myemail@gmail.com' \
--data-urlencode 'EncryptedPasswd=LongEncryptedPassword'
...
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
...
> POST /auth HTTP/1.1
...
< HTTP/2 403 
...
Error=BadAuthentication*
```

What I noticed here, the server responded with HTTP/2 instead of 1.1 in previous version, so I tried force HTTP1.1 in curl params, but still same:

```
 ᐅ docker run php:7.1.17 curl -v -s 'https://android.clients.google.com/auth' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --http1.1 \
--data-urlencode 'Email=myemail@gmail.com' \
--data-urlencode 'EncryptedPasswd=LongEncryptedPassword'
...
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
...
> POST /auth HTTP/1.1
...
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
...
Error=BadAuthentication
```

I have no more ideas how can I force new curl to work as the old one, to make this call happened so I'll be very glad for any advises or ideas.

Comment: *"The version of openssl is same:"* - no, it's not. Look at the output from curl you quoted to see what versions get actually used. In one version it is OpenSSL 1.0.1, in another OpenSSL 1.0.2 - both are not supported any more for many years.

Comment: This does not have anything to do with TLS. There is a successful TLS handshake in both cases since otherwise the inner HTTP exchange (resulting in 200/403) would not be possible in the first place.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich you're right, OpenSSL compiled in curl has different version. At first I though that curl may be using openssl service installed in the system. But I noticed that since that version of curl, the call does not work, even for the latest curl version, not sure why. I also mentioned TLS version as if I force "old" curl to use f.e. TLS 1.1 instead of TLS 1.2, I got `403 Forbidden` instead. So it looks like the HTTP response depends on the handshake too.